# iOS UiImage returns a different signature after app enters the background

Tags: ios, uiimage

```
2012-11-21 11:54:50.607 [10152:907] Current   Image: <UIImage: 0x20819ae0>
2012-11-21 11:54:50.608 [10152:907] EmptyMark Image: <UIImage: 0x20819ae0>
```

After App Enters the background and comes back to foreground.

```
2012-11-21 11:54:57.040 [10152:907] Current   Image: <UIImage: 0x20819ae0>
2012-11-21 11:54:57.042 [10152:907] EmptyMark Image: <UIImage: 0x208cc580>
```

I'm comparing the same image "`emptymark.png`" it is added to a button "Current Image" (logged) to the actual file "EmptyMark Image" (Logged) when I come back to the app after it has been in the background EmptyMark returns different from "Current Image" (the image on the button).

I'm getting "EmptyMark Image" using `[UIImage imageNamed:@"emptymark.png"]`

Should I be holding a reference to `emptymark.png` all the time rather then trying to compare from the file?

Comment: Found this SO question: same issue, as I'm sure you know, is equal is not a great way to do the checking because the memory addresses change. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216167/objective-c-comparing-an-image-against-another-image-that-has-been-previously-s

Comment: I dont think the solution suggested is good in this case. Using `if ([UIImagePNGRepresentation(blackImage) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(greenImage)])' has to create NSData from both images and then has to compare which is not good for app performance if the images are larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hold the reference to `UIImage` as,

```
self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"emptymark.png"];
```

When you are comparing using just `[UIImage imageNamed:@"emptymark.png"]`, it is creating separate objects.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. The above referenced link works however  the ([UIImagePNGRepresentation(blackImage) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(greenImage)])is far from elegant.