# How to compare self.button.currentImage to an image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiimage

I am trying to create a button represented by an image which whenever is pressed changes the image to the other one so that I can know which image is currently selected.

```
- (IBAction)imageWasPressed:(id)sender {
   UIImage *imageWork = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icn_work"];
NSData *data1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageButton.currentImage);
NSData *data2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageWork);

if (data1==data2){
    [self.imageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icn_personal"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];}
}
```

I have also tried this but it didn't work:

```
- (IBAction)imageWasPressed:(id)sender {
if ([[self.imageButton imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icn_work"]]){
    [self.imageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icn_personal"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];}
}
```

The line which changes the images works but I can't compare the two images. Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: have you tried `[data1 isEqual:data2]`?

Comment: Also, as an aside, you probably shouldn't be comparing images to get this information. Keep a BOOL like, `if (self.personalSelected)` changing that when a button is selected instead.

Comment: @daltonclaybrook I've tried it before and it didn't work. It seems that it is working now, lol? Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: Check this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216167/objective-c-comparing-an-image-against-another-image-that-has-been-previously-s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is rather unconventional approach, and I would recommend keeping track of your selection some other way.

But to answer the issue at hand, it does not work because you are comparing pointers, not data.
`data1 *` will always be different to `data2 *`.

From the documentation:
**isEqualToData:**
*Compares the receiving data object to otherData.*

```
- (BOOL)isEqualToData:(NSData *)otherData
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change button image regarding it's state you can assign different images for different states.

```
[self.imageButton setImage:image1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.imageButton setImage:image2 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self.imageButton setImage:image3 forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Since you can get button state and you know what image you set for the state you can get image as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([data1 isEqualToData: data2])
```

instead of

```
if (data1==data2)
```