# Comparing two images whether same or not (iOS)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one compare one image to another to see if they are similar by a certain percentage, on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488732/how-does-one-compare-one-image-to-another-to-see-if-they-are-similar-by-a-certai)

I've found this code and am trying to understand it better:

```
UIImage *img1 = // Some photo;
UIImage *img2 = // Some photo;

NSData *imgdata1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img1);

NSData *imgdata2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img2);

if ([imgdata1 isEqualToData:imgdata2]) {
    NSLog(@"Same Image");
}
```

Will this confirm that image 1 is exactly the same as image 2? Is this method best practice, or is there a better approach to this?

Comment: "Figure 1 design .. Start writing your first app" <- ??

Comment: You should really fix your question. If you are quoting from a book, state it clearly and don't make non-sense references to `Figure 1`, etc

Comment: This kind of comparison is really useful when you have set image using [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:YOUR_IMAGE_FILE_PATH] instead of [UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_IMAGE_NAME">]   because if you have set image using file path and trying to compare its not works so at that time this kind of comparison is useful.

Comment: Actually, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400707/cocoa-touch-comparing-images/23725088#23725088, not the current duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is comparing the two images bit by bit, so yes it's a 100%-comparison.

If you need something faster you can generate an hash from each `UIImage` and compare the two hashes, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1685319/846273).

Comment: This kind of comparison is really useful when you have set image using [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:YOUR_IMAGE_FILE_PATH] instead of [UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_IMAGE_NAME">]   because if you have set image using file path and trying to compare its not works so at that time this kind of comparison is useful.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this link, it talks all about sampling to images to see the percentage similarity: [How does one compare one image to another to see if they are similar by a certain percentage, on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488732/how-does-one-compare-one-image-to-another-to-see-if-they-are-similar-by-a-certai)