# Comparing two JPEG images in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have images that I upload to a server using Amazon S3. I convert them to `NSData`, using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` with `0.75f` compression quality. Now I'd like to compare them and see if they are equal.

With PNG, it's easy, all I had to do is this:

```
if (UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.pictureImageView.image) isEqual:
             UIImagePNGRepresentation(manageItemVC.pictureImage)]) {}
```

as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078283/comparing-two-images-whether-same-or-not-ios). And that would work, but now the images are JPEG, and the comparison isn't working (most likely due to compression), even if I use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`.

`self.pictureImageView.image` is the image from the server that I've loaded into an `UIImageView`, and `manageItemVC.pictureImage` is an image that the user picked from the photo library.

Anyone know how to compare JPEG images?

Comment: Try setting the compression quality to 1 to see if it's definitely the compression that's the difference.

Comment: Apparently it's not the issue, with 1 it's still not working.

Comment: Technically the PNG representations of images aren't unique; in PNG land you pick a linear predictor per scan line and you usually pick that by taking a guess at which will produce the simplest (ie, easiest to gzip compress) output. It's a pretty safe bet that `UIImagePNGRepresentation` will always make the same choices but it isn't a contractual requirement.

Comment: Is there some sort of library or algoritm for JPEG image comparisons with reasonable results?

Answer (score 0):

You can check data's length of two image and compare it.
With my suggestion, i check if two data different about 10000 => two image different.